# Undeclared identifier- C++

Tags: c++

I am doing a project for school and keep running into this reoccurring problem, my code does not seem to run as I have "undeclared identifiers." I have tried renaming them or redefining them but the same errors keep going or more. I am using VS code at the moment and read about maybe it was  VScode itself but I get the same errors regardless.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
    
class bankAccount {
    public:
        int accountNum;
        string accountName;
        string accountType;
        double accountBalance;
        double accountInterest;
        double getInterest;
        double updateBalance;

        bankAccount(){
            accountNum = 0;
            accountName = "";
            accountType = "";
            accountBalance = 0.0;
            accountInterest = 0.0;
        }

        void deposit()
        {
            long amount;
            cout << "\n Please enter the amount you would like to deposit: ";
            cin >> amount;
            accountBalance = accountBalance + amount; 
        }

        void withdraw()
        {
            long amount;
            cout << "Please enter the amount you would like to withdraw: ";
            cin >> amount;
            if (amount <= accountBalance)
            {
                accountBalance = accountBalance - amount;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "You do not have sufficient funds" << endl;
            }
        }

        void interest(){
            double getInterest;
            cout << "Please enter desired interest amount: ";
            cin >> getInterest;
        }

        void update(){
            double updateBalance;
            updateBalance = accountBalance * getInterest;
            accountBalance += updateBalance;
        }

        void print(){
            string print;
            cout << "Welcome Back " << accountName << "," << endl;
            cout << "\n Account Number: " << accountNum << endl;
            cout << "\n Account Type: " << accountType << endl;
            cout << "\n Current Balance: " << accountBalance << endl;
            cout << "\n Account Interest: " << accountInterest << endl;
        }

        void openAccount(){
            cout << "Enter Account Number: ";
            cin >> accountNum;
            cout << "Enter Account Holders Name: ";
            cin >> accountName;
            cout << "Enter Account Type: ";
            cin >> accountType;
            cout << "Enter Initial Balance: ";
            cin >> accountBalance;
            cout << "Enter Interest Rate: ";
            cin >> accountInterest;
        }
};
    
int main() {
    int choice;

    do
    {
        cout << "Please select the following options ";
        cout << "\n 1:View Account";
        cout << "\n 2: Open Account";
        cout << "\n 3: Deposit" ;
        cout << "\n 4: Withdraw ";
        cout << "\n 5: Update account";

        cin >> choice;

        switch (choice)
        {
        case '1':
            print ();
            break;
            
        case '2':
            openAccount();
            break;

        case '3':
            deposit();
            break;

        case '4':
            withdraw();
            break;

        case '5':
            updateBalance();
            break;
        }
    } while (case !=5);
}
```

[image: Error Log in IDE]

Comment: You need an object of type `bankAccount` to call any of your class member functions.

Comment: All of the functions in your `main` are methods on the `bankAccount` type.  You have to create an instance of a `bankAccount` to operate on, and then call those functions from that instance.  e.g. `bankAccount account; account.print();`

Comment: What identifiers? What's the error message?

Comment: This would be the perfect time to study classes in your favourite beginner-level C++ book... member functions need a class or object reference to make sense.

Comment: you don't have any BankAccount in your main, so of course you can't deposit, etc etc.. :)

Comment: Also the ```case``` keyword cannot be used outside of ```switch```

Comment: Please do not post images, instead copy n paste error messages in the question.

Comment: Also, while I like that you allow the users choose their interest, the `interest` *member* function modifies only a *local* variable that shadows the *member* variable with the same name, which remains unmodified.

Comment: Recommendation: Don't write so much code all at once. Errors have an annoying habit of ganging up on you if you let them accumulate. Write a few lines, just enough to do one, easily testable thing. Compile it. Test it. Write a few more lines. Few lines means few places you can make a mistake, so you'll have fewer mistakes to correct in each iteration and a much smaller surface area to have to search for the bug (most of the time).

Answer (score 0):

suggested creating an instance of `class bankAccount` somewhere before switch statement and call the functions like, `instance_of_bankAccount.functionName();`

At end of loop instead of `(case !=5)` it should be `(choice != 5)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you do not have any instance of the class `bankAccount`, which means you try to call the function which actually does not exist. To fix it, you should create an object of the `bankAccount` type before the loop in which you can select the operation you want to perform:

```cpp
int main() {
    int choice;
    bankAccount bankAcc; // this creates the object we need

    do ...
```

And then for every case you wanted to call the function `f()`, add prefix `bankAcc.`, so it becomes `bankAcc.f()`. In your code, it would be:

```cpp
switch (choice) {
    case '1':
        bankAcc.print();
        break;
        
    case '2':
        bankAcc.openAccount();
        break;

    case '3':
        bankAcc.deposit();
        break;

    case '4':
        bankAcc.withdraw();
        break;

    case '5':
        bankAcc.updateBalance();
        break;
}
```

Thanks to it, all functions called will know that they belong to `bankAcc` and they will change properties only of this particular object.

There is also another mistake in your code: did you really mean to use `char`s in your `switch`? At the moment `cin >> choice` reads an int, saves it in `choice` and then in `switch` it gets compared with all values corresponding to cases. The problem is that `1` is very different from `'1'` (which is casted to the value `49`), so inputted `int` will never satisfy conditions from the menu you print.

Also, `while (case !=5)` should be changed to `while (choice != 5)`.